# Is there any way to increase a weapon durability?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I want to stick to a particular weapon in Dark Souls 2, but my weapon is breaking too fast between combats, thus making me switch to another weapon quite often. Is there any way to increase my weapon's durability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bracing+Knuckle+Ring

Decreases the rate durability goes down. To my knowledge...I don't think there's any other way to prolong equipment life.

Comment: The only other thing that I could recommend besides the Bracing Knuckle Ring would be to take a few of that specific weapon around with you, use lower quality ones and then switch to the higher quality when you fight bosses. This works well at least until you get one of the rings.

Answer (score 3):

If you are playing on PC, then durability is drastically affected by the improved framerate on this platform.

[A reddit user has done lots of research into this](http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/2517i8/durability_bug_is_linked_to_framerate/), but the long and short of it is that a lot of actions in the game are measured in number of frames.  As the PC version runs at 60fps, a number of these actions are doubled up.  This mainly affect durability when you swipe through a fading out enemy (after killing them) but it also affects the animation speed of various attacks.

To mitigate the effects, you can use your graphic's card drivers to limit the framerate in DkS2 to 30fps, with the trade-off that movement isn't as fluid.

Comment: Is this for real? I'm about to burst into manic laughter and tears if this is for real.

Answer (score 1):

Use the brace knucle ring found in Lost Bastile

Comment: Kickpuncher11 has already given this answer.

Comment: But this does mention that it's found in Lost Bastille, which the other one does not (although the linked article does).